# Using "style='foo'" in jade to modify css related by pseudo-element ":before"

Tags: css, pug, stylus

EDIT: I have tried to implement user1737909's advice. Using classes (i.e., `.pie.size-{size}:BEFORE`) instead of attribute selectors (i.e., `.pie[data-value={size}]:BEFORE`) has gotten me past the first step and does not prevent the .css file from loading. Unfortunately, I have been unable to set the amount to rotate because of difficulties concatenating strings onto variables in stylus. None of the following work. What is the correct syntax?

```
transform rotate(size+1+'deg')

transform rotate({size}+1+'deg')

foo = size+1+'deg'
transform rotate(foo)

bar = 'rotate('+size+1+'deg)'
transform bar
-webkit-transform bar
```

Failing that, does anyone have any ideas for making a css/html gauge?

---

I am making a radial gauge in CSS which will be displayed for every post in a mixin. I'm using [this code](http://codepen.io/AtomicNoggin/pen/fEish) for making pie charts in CSS as an example. Setting the values of the pie-chart-wedges is as simple as changing the 'data-value' in the below code:

```
<div class="pie" data-start="0" data-value="30"></div>
```

Unfortunately the code corresponds to static css:

```
.pie[data-value="30"]:BEFORE {
    -moz-transform: rotate(31deg); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: rotate(31deg); /* IE */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(31deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: rotate(31deg); /* Opera */
    transform:rotate(31deg);
}
```

This works for the static illustration, but my page will have a variety of different sized wedges. The simplest solution would be to make new entries for all 360 degrees, but this seems like a terrible idea.

My idea is to define the style for each gauge inside the jade mixin at the same time I'm setting the 'data-value'. Something like:

```
pieStyle = '-moz-tranform: rotate('+ degreesPlusOne + 'deg); -ms-tranform: rotate('+ degreesPlusOne + 'deg); -o-tranform: rotate('+ degreesPlusOne + 'deg); -webkit-tranform: rotate('+ degreesPlusOne + 'deg); tranform: rotate('+ degreesPlusOne + 'deg)'

.pie2(data-start='0', data-value=degrees, style=pieStyle)
```

Unfortunately, the style to be set isn't for '.pie' but rather '.pie:BEFORE'. Is there any way I could set a style with this pseudo-element within a mixin?

Alternatively is there a way to solve this within stylus? The site I'm working on is a news aggregator and any user will see dozens and likely hundreds of these gauges. In such an environment would I be better off in the not-so-long-term to simply transmit all 360 sets as part of the css and reference them in cache in the future?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do that with stylus

```
for size in 30 60 180 360
  .pie.size-{size}
    transform: rotate(size+1)
```

With nib, `transform` will have all its prefix :).

Comment: The syntax is `transform rotate(61deg)` not `transform rotate(61)`. Concatenating 'deg' on thusly `transform rotate(size+1+'deg')` doesn't work. Thanks for the tip about nib.